# How to structure asynchronous code for a single method that has 2 tasks as anonymous functions that use Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library, anonymous-function

What would code look like for a single method that has 2 anonymous functions inside, which are both tasks that use Task.WhenAll so that they run in parallel but wait for both to finish before the method continues and returns?

pseudo code:

```
MethodX
{ 
  Task () => {do work}
  Task () => {do work}
  Task.WhenAll()
}
```

Comment: It's literally [WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874(v=vs.110).aspx), not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question? With   `WhenAll(t1, t2)` ?

Comment: Looking for a C# example in the same form as pseudo code. Just thought I would see how others would present it.

Answer (score 0):

I like:

```
async Task MethodX() {
    Task x = ...
    Task y = ...

    await x;
    await y;
}
```

Although I'd probably add a sync hot-path:

```
Task MethodX() {
    async Task Awaited(Task a, Task b) {
        await a;
        await b;
    }
    Task x = ...;
    Task y = ...;

    if (x.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion &
        y.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        return Task.CompletedTask; // sync

    return Awaited(x, y); // async
}
```

but this would work too:

```
Task MethodX() {
    Task x = ...
    Task y = ...

    return Task.WhenAll(x, y);
}
```

---

Another approach is `Parallel`:

```
Parallel.Invoke(thingA, thingB);
```

Comment: well the await, await means task x has to finish before task y starts right?

Comment: @AshleyMedway nope! if they're actually async, then they should be concurrent here; but it depends a lot on the concurrency model of the two tasks

Comment: @AshleyMedway If you start task y after awaiting x, then  yes, you don't start it until after the await.  If you start it before awaiting x, then you have started it before task x finishes.  This code does the latter, not the former.  You could write either though.

Comment: Thanks @Servy, that's is what I thought but wasn't sure when I saw the answer

Comment: Would methodX need to be marked task "Task MethodX" or could it also just be marked "async"as in my original pseudo code. the main objective is that both task run concurrent but the method doesn't continue until both tasks are finished

Comment: @StackMan that should work fine either way, *as long as** those tasks actually are async. If they complete synchronously: this entire code path is already synchronous, so if they are actually synchronous jobs pretending to be async: you'll need to use `Parallel` or similar